# Nvidia Nsight Eclipse CPU to GPU Refactoring

Tags: refactoring, gpu, nvidia, nsight

I have just installed the Nvidia Nsight Eclipse Edition to try the announced CPU to GPU refactoring. Unfortunately, I could not apply this refactoring because I even did not find this functionality neither did I find information or examples on this in the web.

What I did so far:

- Created different Projects with Nsight (C++ Project, C/C++ CUDA Project) with different Toolchains
- edit the source file to contain the following code as I thought this simple axpy algorithm should be possible to refactor to a GPU Kernel:

  ```
  int test() {
      const int N = 10;
      float y[N] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
      float x[N] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0};
      float a = 1.0;

      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
          y[i] = a * x[i] + y[i];
      }
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- Searched the context menu while clicked on the for loop for any refactoring as CPU to GPU

As I haven't been successful with this, could anyone manage to use the CPU to GPU refactoring? And if so, how? Maybe my understanding of this refactoring is completely wrong.

It is described here in their press release: [link](http://nvidianews.nvidia.com/Releases/NVIDIA-Releases-CUDA-5-Making-Programming-With-World-s-Most-Pervasive-Parallel-Computing-Platform-Even-Easier-88b.aspx)

Comment: Could you identify a reference to "the announced CPU to GPU refactoring" that you are referring to?

Comment: @RobertCrovella He is meaning what is said here http://nvidianews.nvidia.com/Releases/NVIDIA-Releases-CUDA-5-Making-Programming-With-World-s-Most-Pervasive-Parallel-Computing-Platform-Even-Easier-88b.aspx